# How to write a code for a flattening of nested lists more concisely

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, flatten

I have a collection of nested lists in a list.

Think about the data like this:

```
numberlist1 = [[[1,2]]]
numberlist2 = [[[1,2]]]
```

This works exactly how I want it to work. However, it looks messy, and I am sure there is a better way to do it. Can anyone help me format this code?

```py
list(chain(*chain(*(chain.from_iterable([numberlist1, numberlist2])))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to write your original:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(chain(numberlist1, numberlist2))))
```

Making a shorter alias:

```
flat = chain.from_iterable

list(flat(flat(chain(numberlist1, numberlist2))))
```

The list comprehension – works best if you can pick meaningful names:

```
[c for a in chain(numberlist1, numberlist2) for b in a for c in b]
```

f u n c t i o n a l

```
def repeat(count, f):
    def g(x):
        for i in range(count):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return g


list(repeat(3, flat)((numberlist1, numberlist2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`more_itertools.collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collapse) shortens this:

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


nlst1 = [[[1, 2]]]
nlst2 = [[[1, 3]]]
```

**Code**

```
list(mit.collapse(nlst1 + nlst2))
# [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party package.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.